# Need to use select query to check time from 10:00 PM(22:00) To 6:00 AM(06:00) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to check the given or selected time is in between start and end time,
For Example Given time is 10:12(AM) and in database we have 06:00 to 14:00

[image: My sample records]

And my query is

```
SELECT * FROM erp_shift WHERE '10:12' between Start_Time AND End_Time
```

But For 2:00(AM), Above query not working (return an empty row)

```
SELECT * FROM erp_shift WHERE '02:01' between Start_Time AND End_Time
```

Help me to find a way to fix it.

Comment: here is a day overlapped between start and end time. So you need to take care of that also

Comment: You don't have any records "between" 22:01 and 06:00. Querying them is the same as asking for a the set of all numbers between 5 and 4. It's empty!

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about a way to manage when Start_Time > End_Time, here is a solution :

```
SELECT * FROM erp_shift
WHERE (Start_Time <= End_Time and :Mytime between Start_Time and End_Time) or
      (End_Time < Start_Time and (:Mytime <= End_Time or :Mytime >= Start_Time ))
```

Comment: Has Error - SELECT * FROM erp_shift 
WHERE (Start_Time <= End_Time and '00:01' between Start_Time and End_Time) or 
(End_Time < Start_Time and ('00:01' <= End_Time or '00:01' >= Start_Time )                    [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: forgot a closing )

Comment: Sorry i am not study about this query. Query working for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM erp_shift 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('10:12','%H:%i') between STR_TO_DATE(Start_Time,'%H:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(End_Time,'%H:%i:%s');
```

For testing:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10:12','%H:%i') between STR_TO_DATE('10:00:00','%H:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('12:00:00','%H:%i:%s');
```

Which prints 1 (for true) as expected.

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/17686).

Comment: not working, his problem is more like that  : SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10:12','%H:%i') between STR_TO_DATE('10:00:00','%H:%i:%s') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE('06:00:00','%H:%i:%s');

Comment: In my case one time today means next time in tomorrow(This is not working SELECT STR_TO_DATE('02:12','%H:%i') between STR_TO_DATE('22:00:00','%H:%i:%s') AND  STR_TO_DATE('6:00:00','%H:%i:%s');)